# node js temporary file location

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, file-upload, server

Please help I am not able to locate my file after it has been uploaded even though it says on the instructions the file will be placed on a temporary folder on my computer I am running windows

```
  var http = require('http');
    var formidable = require('formidable');

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      res.write('File uploaded');
      res.end();
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: What is the value of `files` inside your `form.parse` callback?

Comment: Check the output of `console.log(os.tmpdir());` see in https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#ostmpdir

Comment: RTFM: `options.uploadDir {string} - default os.tmpdir(); the directory for placing file uploads in. You can move them later by using fs.rename().` https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable#options

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you provided for handling file uploads using Node.js and the `formidable` library.

```js
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      res.write('File uploaded');
      res.end();
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Regarding the location of the uploaded file, the `formidable` library defaults to storing uploaded files in a temporary directory on the server. If you want to specify a different directory, you can use the `uploadDir` option when creating the `IncomingForm` object:

```js
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
  uploadDir: '/path/to/your/desired/directory'
});
```

Make sure to replace `/path/to/your/desired/directory` with the actual path to the directory where you want to store the uploaded files. After specifying the `uploadDir`, the uploaded files should be stored in that directory instead of the default temporary directory.